# How to understand the view hierarchy dumped by "adb shell dumpsys activity"?

Tags: android, adb, dumpsys

I use `adb shell dumpsys activity <package_name>/<activityName>` to dump the view hierarchy of the activity.

In the output, there is a section called `View Hierarchy:` and I can see the hierarchy tree. But I found difficulties to understand some part of the output. For example, a node in the tree is displayed like:

```
com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView{d1de4b9 VFED..C.. ........ 0,0-288,196 #7f090074 app:id/article_menu_bookmark}
```

Some part of the information is easy to understand such as class name, id name, and view bounds, etc.

But what does `VFED..C.. ........` mean? How to interpret those characters? I may guess `V` stands for `visible`, but this is what I guess. Can anyone points out some sources (e.g., Android source code) where I can find the meaning of those outputs?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44159455

Comment: You have much better alternatives if you want to display the View hierarchy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586685/is-there-a-way-to-get-current-activitys-layout-and-views-via-adb/

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks, that's the answer.